# Security in Web Api

Tags: security, rest, asp.net-web-api

I have just created my first rest service using apicontroller. I am using it with web forms instead of mvc-4. How can i go about implementing security in web service. Keeping in mind that service may be used by clients other than browser how would one go on setting up security. 
when we authenticate ourselves from browser against an asp.net application that is using forms authentication, the app returns an authentication cookie which is forwarded by browser on each subsequent request and application knows that user is signed in by decrypting the cookie.
I was watching a [tutorial on plural sight](http://www.pluralsight-training.net/microsoft/Courses/TableOfContents?courseName=aspnetwebapi) about security of web api. They advocate that we should just have a method that can log in users if json data is passed. Once logged in the method will return auth cookie to client (browser and other service clients) and clients should send this cookie on each subsequent request to authorize themselves. Is this auth scheme normal for web services or there is some other recommended way? The question is more about what to implement than how to implement?

**Edit:** The idea i got from @AliOstad's answer to this [question](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/10060846/asp-net-web-api-custom-authentication-requirement-for-mobile-client) is that i should create a separate login method for my service that should ideally work on https and this method should return an encrypted auth header including user's email and time of issue. Once client has acquired the token he can go on to use the service by passing this token in auth header (to andriod app etc.) and I see no problem if the data service (as opposed to login service which should work on https) is operating on http since the token would expire after x amount of minutes. On server side its perfectly ok but how would my client know that his token has expired and he needs to go and get another token before getting the data from data service? My second concern is that if i implement it this way how would i handle ajax calls to data service that are made by asp.net application (asp.net application and web api are running on same application). There (in javascript), i would either need auth token or username and password to get authentication token and neither of them seems feasible?
Any ideas how should i handle these scenarios?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Dominick Baier is an authority in this subject and has a series on this subject in his blog. See the first of the series [here](http://www.leastprivilege.com/ASPNETWebAPISecurity1IntroducingThinktectureIdentityModelHttp.aspx).

I cannot really summarise in a sensible small answer and I think you need to go through the posts.

---

## UPDATE

> how would my client know that his token has expired

Unlike forms authentication, when user has an expired token and redirected to login screen, Web API communicates with HTTP response codes - since very likely the client is a machine not a human user.

So client agent would not know if it has an expired token, instead when it connects your API using its expired token, a **401** (Unauthorised) response is returned. At this point client will try acquiring a new token.

> how would i handle ajax calls to data service that are made by asp.net application

They would not make an AJAX call, they will either:

- Make a direct call (create the object and call methods) if it is on the same box
- Use HttpClient to make a call to the service and use the data

Comment: thanks a lot. it made things a lot clearer. when i talk about ajax calls i mean to say calls from asp.net site to web api service. obviously in js code (running on my aspx page) i would not have security token to call web api service even though the user is logged into the site.

Comment: what i have learned so far is that web api inherits the Pricipal object of underlying hosting environment (asp.net in this case). This inheritance can be turned off from global configuration object. My idea here is to turn of inheritance if user agent is anything but a web browser. I think i have made myself clear? Do you see anything wrong with this idea?

Comment: Thanks Aliostad for the followup. i have almost created a message handler for tackling security. i would put it somewhere on the net and let you have a look at it.